# Linux not detecting speakers

Tags: linux, linux-mint, audio

Linux Mint, Linux Kubuntu and Kali Linux all do not detect my speakers. This happened right when I got the preinstalled Windows Inspiron 5400 AIO (DELL), using linux mint live usb, here are the system's info:

```
Kernel: 5.15.0-56-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.3.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 5.6.5
 tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: muffin dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 21.1 Vera base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
Machine:
Type: Desktop System: Dell product: Inspiron 5400 AIO v: N/A serial: <superuser required>
 Chassis: type: 13 serial: <superuser required>
Mobo: Dell model: 0MHWCY v: A00 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: Dell v: 1.18.0
 date: 03/09/2023
CPU:
Info: quad core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i7-1165G7 bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Tiger Lake
 rev: 1 cache: L1: 320 KiB L2: 5 MiB L3: 12 MiB
Speed (MHz): avg: 2470 high: 4350 min/max: 400/4700 cores: 1: 2112 2: 1367 3: 1891 4: 4350
 5: 3663 6: 1448 7: 680 8: 4249 bogomips: 44851
Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
Device-1: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] vendor: Dell driver: i915 v: kernel ports:
 active: HDMI-A-1 empty: HDMI-A-2 bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:9a49
Device-2: NVIDIA GP108M [GeForce MX330] vendor: Dell driver: nouveau v: kernel pcie:
 speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 4 bus-ID: 02:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:1d16
Device-3: Realtek Integrated_Webcam_HD type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 3-5:4
 chip-ID: 0bda:5687
Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa
 gpu: i915 display-ID: :0 screens: 1
Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1920x1080 s-dpi: 96
Monitor-1: HDMI-1 mapped: HDMI-A-1 model: Dell Inspiron 540X res: 1920x1080 dpi: 93
 diag: 595mm (23.4")
OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.5 direct render: Yes
Audio:
Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio vendor: Dell driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
 bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:a0c8
Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-56-generic running: yes
Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel bus-ID: 00:14.3 chip-ID: 8086:a0f0
IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter>
Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Dell driver: r8169
 v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: 3000 bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8168
IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
Device-1: Intel AX201 Bluetooth type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 3-10:5 chip-ID: 8087:0026
Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 3.0 lmp-v: 5.2
 sub-v: 237e
Drives:
Local Storage: total: 1.17 TiB used: 1.04 TiB (88.8%)
ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Toshiba model: KBG40ZNS256G NVMe KIOXIA 256GB size: 238.47 GiB
 speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 serial: <filter> temp: 42.9 C
ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: Toshiba model: MQ04ABF100 size: 931.51 GiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s
 serial: <filter>
ID-3: /dev/sdb type: USB vendor: Kingston model: DataTraveler 3.0 size: 28.87 GiB
 serial: <filter>
Partition:
ID-1: / size: 7.63 GiB used: 180.4 MiB (2.3%) fs: overlay source: ERR-102
ID-2: /var/log size: 25.79 GiB used: 684 KiB (0.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdb3
Swap:
Alert: No swap data was found.
USB:
Hub-1: 1-0:1 info: Hi-speed hub with single TT ports: 1 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s
 chip-ID: 1d6b:0002
Hub-2: 2-0:1 info: Super-speed hub ports: 4 rev: 3.1 speed: 10 Gb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0003
Hub-3: 3-0:1 info: Hi-speed hub with single TT ports: 12 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s
 chip-ID: 1d6b:0002
Device-1: 3-1:2 info: Razer USA Cynosa V2 type: Keyboard,Mouse driver: hid-generic,usbhid
 rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s chip-ID: 1532:025e
Device-2: 3-4:3 info: Razer USA DeathAdder Essential type: Mouse,Keyboard
 driver: hid-generic,usbhid rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s chip-ID: 1532:0098
Device-3: 3-5:4 info: Realtek Integrated_Webcam_HD type: Video driver: uvcvideo rev: 2.0
 speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 0bda:5687
Device-4: 3-6:7 info: Melfas LGDisplay Incell Touch type: HID
 driver: hid-generic,hid-multitouch,usbhid rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s chip-ID: 1fd2:8105
Device-5: 3-10:5 info: Intel AX201 Bluetooth type: Bluetooth driver: btusb rev: 2.0
 speed: 12 Mb/s chip-ID: 8087:0026
Hub-4: 4-0:1 info: Super-speed hub ports: 4 rev: 3.1 speed: 10 Gb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0003
Device-1: 4-2:2 info: Kingston DataTraveler 100 G3/G4/SE9 G2/50 type: Mass Storage
 driver: usb-storage rev: 3.2 speed: 5 Gb/s chip-ID: 0951:1666
Sensors:
System Temperatures: cpu: 52.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nouveau temp: 54.0 C
Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 1397
Repos:
Packages: apt: 2088
Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
 1: deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 21.1 _Vera_ - Release amd64 20221217]/ jammy main
Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
 1: deb http: //packages.linuxmint.com vera main upstream import backport
 2: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted universe multiverse
 3: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
 4: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
 5: deb http: //security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
Info:
Processes: 280 Uptime: 8m Memory: 15.27 GiB used: 2.4 GiB (15.7%) Init: systemd v: 249
runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.3.0 alt: 11 Client: Unknown python3.10 client inxi: 3.3.13
```

Requested edit: The speakers are built-in, yes. They work with Windows 11 normally. (Not sure if saying it's Realtek[image: Image of sound details] would be useful but I think that's the speaker driver)

Output settings only has "Dummy output"
aplay -l shows:

```
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC274 Analog [ALC274 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 13: HDMI 7 [HDMI 7]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 14: HDMI 8 [HDMI 8]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 15: HDMI 9 [HDMI 9]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 16: HDMI 10 [HDMI 10]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 17: HDMI 11 [HDMI 11]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

pacmd list-sinks shows:

```
  * index: 0
    name: <auto_null>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 1.45 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 1
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 2.51 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    module: 14
    properties:
        device.description = "Dummy Output"
        device.class = "abstract"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us i) what kind of speakers are these? How are they connected? Are you talking about on board speakers, or external speakers? ii) assuming they are on board, integrated speakers, do they work in Windows?

Comment: Edited, anything else?

Comment: Have you tried the audio settings of your desktop environment? Are you using the right output?

Comment: If you mean the linux environment, it only shows "Dummy output" in all three linux distros

Comment: Please add all this to your question. Ideally show us a screenshot of the audio settings.  Also, add the output of `aplay -l` and `pacmd list-sinks`, those would be relevant. You might want to check out [Speakers not detected or playing sound](https://askubuntu.com/q/920568) and [No sound on HDMI Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1256043) for some other suggestions.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/920568/speakers-not-detected-or-playing-sound This helped! Can I get a brief explanation into why that worked? There was only one card, and running the command fixed it?